# Custom Email verification in a single orchestration step in AD B2C Custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a multi-step custom policy that first collects email from user and sends a verification code to the user when user clicks continue. The journey works fine. But the thing is validation of code is happening in next step. I need to bring that code validation in to the first orchestration step. I'm following the below doc to implement this journey:
"https://github.com/yoelhor/aadb2c-verification-code"

My technical profile is like the following:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail-FirstStep">
  <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider,        Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
    <Item Key="language.button_continue">Send verification email</Item>
    <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyEmailAsReadOnly" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-API-SendVerificationEmail" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

and the validation tech profile as follows:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SendVerificationEmail">
  <DisplayName>Sign-Up send link</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine,       Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://myweb.azurewebsites.net/api/Identity/SendVerificationCode</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

It cant be achieved currently, to call the REST API, the form must be submitted and that will cause the orchestration step to complete and move to the next one.

In a few weeks we will release how to achieve this, and without the use of an external REST API to generate and verify the OTP Codes. Stay tuned.