# Pre-Condition evaluation for validation technical profile in azure ad b2c custom policy is not working

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a technical profile having 3 output claims. One of these three is a "RadioSingleSelect". Based on the value selected for the radio button need to decide the validation profile for that technical profile work or not. Below is my tech profile and created claim type

```xml
     <ClaimType Id="IsVisible">
        <DisplayName>Is this visble?</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <UserInputType>RadioSingleSelect</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
          <Enumeration Text="Yes" Value="true" SelectByDefault="false" />
          <Enumeration Text="No" Value="false" SelectByDefault="false" />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
```

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Profile1">
    <DisplayName>Profile1</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
        <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
        <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>           
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="name" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="code" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="name" Required="true" /> 
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="IsVisible" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="CheckIsVisible">
        <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>IsVisible</Value>
            <Value>true</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

My expected output is, if the user choose "Yes" for "IsVisible", then i need to skip the Validation Technical Profile "CheckIsVisible"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its case sensitive when the claim type is boolean, change

```xml
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="CheckIsVisible">
        <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>IsVisible</Value>
            <Value>true</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
```

to

```xml
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="CheckIsVisible">
        <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>IsVisible</Value>
            <Value>True</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
```

Comment: Can you please look into this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776592/custom-email-verification-in-a-single-orchestration-step-in-ad-b2c-custom-polici